# pygame import error osx 10.7.5 python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, osx-lion, pygame

My question is similar to

[Installing Pygame for Mac OS X 10.6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8),

[unable to import pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088051/unable-to-import-pygame), and

[Pygame for Python 3.2 on mac - import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769624/pygame-for-python-3-2-on-mac-import-error).

When I try to import pygame *, I get `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so`

I'm trying to figure out whether or not it applies to my system.  I don't remember how I installed pygame, but if I do `port search pygame`, I get

> ```
> py-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py24-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py25-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py26-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py27-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py31-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> py32-game @1.9.1 (python, devel, multimedia, graphics)
> ```

My hunch was that 
`port install py32-game` would fix the issue, but It doesn't change anything (maybe python needs to somehow point to a different version of pygame?).  Does anyone have experience with my particular config?  It's unclear to me how to ascertain which version of pygame I need to be running.

OSX 10.7.5
Python 2.7.3

Comment: I tried downloading http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip, but it doesn't fix the issue.  Maybe I have something wrong with my path??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, It turned out to be two issues:

1. pygame needed to be installed again after I switched python versions from the OSX native version to the ports version of 2.7 (I uninstalled the macports version)
2. my .bash_profile path was messed up and I needed to export the correct locations to the newly installed version so that python could find what it needed